# Open a PDF document in a new tab with Auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

Open a PDF in a new tab when you have no auth can be done like this:

```
<a ng-href="/api/resources/{{project.prj_id}}" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>
```

When I have auth, I need to go via $http since I'm using $httpInterceptor to attach auth:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');

...


this.$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/api/resources/' + this.id,
   responseType: "arraybuffer"
}).then((successResp)=> {   
   // Open in a new tab from here!
}, (errResp) => {
   // Error handling
});
```

How do I open the PDF in a new tab from my success result? I also don't want any pop-blockers to interfere.

Comment: You cannot easily do that with AJAX.  Your original hyperlink should work fine with cookie auth.

Comment: I cant. I'm using $httpInterceptor to attach to auth stuff in header.

Comment: You could probably do this by making a `data:` or blob URI from the response and opening that.  It'd probably be slower, though.

Comment: You need to use ```window.open('url', '_blank');``` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open Let me know if this works!

Comment: @JonathanBrizio. Pop-up blockers blocks window.open in callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser blocks your page, you can use the following approach triggering a click:

```
$('#yourDownloadButton').click(function() {
    var newTabToOpen = window.open('url', '_blank');
    newTabToOpen.location;
});
```

Keep rocking!

Comment: Its still blocks.